# Filter data using textbox and view it in the listview in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc

I want to display  the result in listview that i written in the texbox can you pls help me?

Comment: on exiting the textbox?  Live?  Not much info here on what you actually want to occur, or what you have tried so far.

Comment: I use textbox,ListView, and Button This is My Code: Me.ListView1.Items.Clear()
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Select PatientID,PatientName FROM patientpersonal WHERE PatientName = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", con)
        read = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While read.Read
            Dim str(2) As String
            Dim itm As ListViewItem
            str(1) = read.Item(0)
            str(2) = read.Item(1)
            itm = New ListViewItem(str)
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
        End While
        con.Close()

Comment: But the problem is i need to type the whole name of the data so that the result will show. I want that even though you just type one let it will show some of the result the is similart to the data inputted in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for the ability to search based on criteria similar to what you type in the textbox (I think that is what you are asking), then change you SQL statement to be

```
WHERE PatientName LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

instead of =.  The problem is that you will only get results back on the = if it matches exactly.  The LIKE statement will find things similar to what is entered.  THe % is a wildcard character meaning "any number of characters".  Note that it will work for MOST dbs.  If it does not work for you, look up wildcard characters for your db and replace the %s.